# MySQL order of execution

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, subquery

I am running a very long query described below.
It fetches the next needed action for each account on an automation system.

I.e.

```
SELECT Account.id, 
(IFNULL(**Should send message query**, 
    IFNULL(**Should check inbox**, NULL))) as nextTask FROM Account
```

In reality the string of IFNULL's is around 10, each is quite a complicated subquery.

I want to know if MySQL will compute the values for following IFNULL expression if the first is satisfied. That is, if an account should send a message, it shouldn't bother computing the subquery for **Should check inbox**

Is this how MySQL works?

What's the difference between this and CASE WHEN's

E.g.

```
CASE WHEN **Should send message** THEN **Should send message**
    WHEN **Should check inbox** THEN **Should check inbox**
END
```

I just want to get the CPU usage down for this query.

Comment: First of all: Use [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, howcome? What's the difference in this case?

Comment: "What's the difference"? - It's shorter. And it's SQL standard compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying is best done using [`COALESCE(value,...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no
>   non-NULL values.

So it would be:

```
SELECT
    Account.id, 
    COALESCE(
        **Should send message query**, 
        **Should check inbox**
    ) as nextTask
FROM Account
```

Now to your actual question

> I want to know if MySQL will compute the values for following [IFNULL]
>   expression if the first is satisfied.

The engine has no reason to do so. You can test it with the following script:

```
set @executed1 = 'no';
set @executed2 = 'no';

select coalesce(
  @executed1 := 'yes', -- evaluates to non null
  @executed2 := 'yes'
);

select @executed1, @executed2;
```

Result:

```
@executed1 | @executed2
yes        | no
```

As you can see, the second expression is not executed, since the first one has been evaluated to a non NULL value.

```
set @executed1 = 'no';
set @executed2 = 'no';

select coalesce(
  nullif(@executed1 := 'yes', 'yes'), -- evaluates to null
  @executed2 := 'yes'
);

select @executed1, @executed2;
```

Result:

```
@executed1 | @executed2
yes        | yes
```

Here both expressions have been executed, because the first one has been evaluated to NULL.

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qkJUrDFebkPYmGgc3mUEb7/0)

I would say - The same is true for `IFNULL`. But I wouldn't use it. At least not in your case.